# Get the key without the value in foreach loop

Tags: arrays, foreach, key

I am wondering if it is possible to get the key without the value in foreach loop. I don't use the value anywhere in the code so I would like to exclude it.

so instead of this
`foreach($array as $key => $value) {`

having something like this
`foreach($array as $key) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

```
foreach(array_keys($array) as $key) {
  echo $key;
}
```